# There is an error in XML document (2, 2)

Tags: xml-serialization

I have searched similar questions and still can't figure this out.

Inner Exception: `{"<xml xmlns=''> was not expected."}`

I am pulling the XML from an online source so cannot make changes to it.
http://api.ustream.tv/xml/user/techcrunch/listAllVideos?key=devkey

I generated the XSD file from XML using visual studio 2010. I used xsd.exe to generate the VB class.

Here is all of my code:
Form1:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Serialization


Public Class Form1
Private Const strURL As String = "http://api.ustream.tv/xml/user/techcrunch/listAllVideos?key=devkey"



Private Sub btnProcess_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnProcess.Click
    Dim ds As New NewDataSet()
    Dim myReader As TextReader = New StreamReader("../../listAllVideos.xml")
    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(NewDataSet))
    ds = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(myReader), NewDataSet)
    myReader.Close()
End Sub


End Class
```

listAllVideos.xml: (shortened)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<results>
<array key="0">
    <id>1916735</id>
    <title><![CDATA[The TechCrunch Office live 8/2/09 04:50PM]]></title>
    <protected>FALSE</protected>
    <description><![CDATA[8/2/09 04:50PM PST]]></description>
    <createdAt><![CDATA[2009-08-02 16:13:54]]></createdAt>
    <rating>3.000</rating>
    <lengthInSecond>2146.777</lengthInSecond>
    <totalViews>1943</totalViews>
    <codecIsForLiveHttp>0</codecIsForLiveHttp>
    <serverId>992</serverId>
    <videoName><![CDATA[1_170_1249254834012]]></videoName>
    <url><![CDATA[http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/1916735]]></url>
    <embedTag><![CDATA[<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="320" height="260" id="utv445187" name="utv_n_638715"><param name="flashvars" value="autoplay=false&vid=1916735" /><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="src" value="http://www.ustream.tv/flash/viewer.swf" /><embed flashvars="autoplay=false&vid=1916735" width="320" height="260" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" id="utv445187" name="utv_n_638715" src="http://www.ustream.tv/flash/viewer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" /></object>]]></embedTag>
    <liveHttpUrl><![CDATA[]]></liveHttpUrl>
    <imageUrl>
        <small><![CDATA[http://static-cdn2.ustream.tv/videopic/0/1/1/1916/1916735/1_170_1916735_120x90_b_1:1.jpg]]></small>
        <medium><![CDATA[http://static-cdn2.ustream.tv/videopic/0/1/1/1916/1916735/1_170_1916735_320x240_b_1:1.jpg]]></medium>
    </imageUrl>
    <sourceChannel>
        <id>170</id>
        <url><![CDATA[http://www.ustream.tv/channel/170]]></url>
    </sourceChannel>
</array>
</results>
<msg><![CDATA[]]></msg>
<error><![CDATA[]]></error>
<processTime>TRUE</processTime>
<version><![CDATA[mashery-r10]]></version>
</xml>
```

listAllVideos.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="xml">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="results">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="array">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="id" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
                <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="protected" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="createdAt" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="rating" type="xs:decimal" />
                <xs:element name="lengthInSecond" type="xs:decimal" />
                <xs:element name="totalViews" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
                <xs:element name="codecIsForLiveHttp" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                <xs:element name="serverId" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
                <xs:element name="videoName" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="url" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="embedTag" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="liveHttpUrl" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="imageUrl">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="small" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element name="medium" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="sourceChannel">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                      <xs:element name="url" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="msg" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="error" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="processTime" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="version" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The VB class is really long and it won't let me post it. Thanks for your time.

```
Partial Public Class NewDataSet
Inherits Global.System.Data.DataSet

Private tablexml As xmlDataTable

Private tableresults As resultsDataTable

Private tablearray As arrayDataTable

Private tableimageUrl As imageUrlDataTable

Private tablesourceChannel As sourceChannelDataTable

Private relationxml_results As Global.System.Data.DataRelation

Private relationresults_array As Global.System.Data.DataRelation

Private relationarray_imageUrl As Global.System.Data.DataRelation

Private relationarray_sourceChannel As Global.System.Data.DataRelation

Private _schemaSerializationMode As Global.System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode = Global.System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema
```

Comment: Post just the first bit of the VB file: the definition of the "Xml" and class and the `NewDataSet` class.

Comment: I'm concerned that you want to treat this as a DataSet.

Comment: John the xsd.exe tool generated a class that contained a dataset. The XML is considerably larger than what I posted. You can see the XML here: http://api.ustream.tv/xml/user/techcrunch/listAllVideos?key=devkey

Comment: I added as much as I could above John, thank you so much for your time.

Comment: John it generated so much code for the class using xsd.exe that it is 63 pages if I copy the code to microsoft word. This seems a bit over the top. Is this common behavior for the xsd.exe tool? Can you recommend another means of doing this?

Comment: Try generating the classes using `xsd /c`. This should give you a class named something like `xml`. Use that instead of `NewDataSet`. If your XML were a real dataset, then your XML would be starting with `<NewDataSet>`. Also, what were the first few lines _before_ the `Partial Public Class NewDataSet`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an xml element can have the name "xml" can it?

http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-common-syn

> [Definition: A Name is an Nmtoken with a restricted set of initial characters.] Disallowed initial characters for Names include digits, diacritics, the full stop and the hyphen.
>
> Names beginning with the string "xml", or with any string which would match (('X'|'x') ('M'|'m') ('L'|'l')), are reserved for standardization in this or future versions of this specification.

Comment: +1 why nobody follows recommendations? It's written that anyway, xml parsers should parse tokens as normal, even if they are contains colon characters, but why someone should provide an invalid XML?

Comment: yes, it can, but will not corresponds to the w3c standards thought

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `NewDataSet` class would match XML starting with `<NewDataSet>`, but you're passing XML that starts with `<xml>`. That's why it's unexpected.

Either wrap the XML with `<NewDataSet></NewDataSet>`, or else generate your classes by using the `xsd /c` command, which will only generate "plain" classes and not a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

All of your XML Elements are correctly formatted. You can place this in an XML format validator such as OygenXML or your favorite XML Editor to validate that. The issue is with your values, you will need to encode the special characters correctly. This is a list of XML's special set of characters that cannot be used in normal XML strings. These characters are:

```
1. & - &amp; 
2. < - &lt; 
3. > - &gt; 
4. " - &quot; 
5. ' - &#39;
```

You will want to format the values correctly in order to get beyond this error. I suggest using looping through the values and using **System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(stringValue);** to encode the values.